# Extract string when preceding number or combo of preceding characters is unknown

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's an example string:

```
++++#foo+bar+baz++#yikes
```

I need to extract `foo` and only `foo` from there or a similar scenario.

The `+` and the `#` are the only characters I need to worry about.

However, regardless of what precedes `foo`, it needs to be stripped or ignored. Everything else after it needs to as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `match()` method.

```
var str = "++++#foo+bar+baz++#yikes";
var res = str.match(/\w+/g);

console.log(res[0]);  // foo
console.log(res);     // foo,bar,baz,yikes
```

Or use `exec`

```
var str = "++++#foo+bar+baz++#yikes";
var match = /(\w+)/.exec(str);
alert(match[1]); // foo
```

Using `exec` with a `g` modifier (global) is meant to be used in a loop getting all sub matches.

```
var str = "++++#foo+bar+baz++#yikes";
var re  = /\w+/g;
var match;

while (match = re.exec(str)) {
   // In array form, match is now your next match..
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yep I wrote the exact console.log a minute ago.  I like this since the `+` is used to separate strings. So, although I only need the first one in the series now, I'm ready to pluck any of them with this approach (I think).

Comment: Note that your first code block doesn't return `'foo'` it returns `['foo']`.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
/\++#(\w+)/
```

and catch the capturing group one.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm going with the Match but yours helped me better understand more abou regex.

Answer (score 1):

How exactly do `+` and `#` play a role in identifying foo? If you just want any string that follows `#` and is terminated by `+` that's as simple as:

```
var foostring = '++++#foo+bar+baz++#yikes';
var matches = (/\#([^+]+)\+/g).exec(foostring);
if (matches.length > 1) {
    // all the matches are found in elements 1 .. length - 1 of the matches array
    alert('found ' + matches[1] + '!'); // alerts 'found foo!'
}
```

To help you more specifically, please provide information about the possible variations of your data and how you would go about identifying the token you want to extract even in cases of differing lengths and characters.

If you are just looking for the first segment of text preceded and followed by any combination of `+` and `#`, then use:

```
var foostring = '++++#foo+bar+baz++#yikes';
var result = foostring.match(/[^+#]+/);
// will be the single-element array, ['foo'], or null.
```

Depending on your data, using `\w` may be too restrictive as it is equivalent to `[a-zA-z0-9_]`. Does your data have anything else such as punctuation, dashes, parentheses, or any other characters that you do want to include in the match? Using the negated character class I suggest will catch *every* token that does not contain a `+` or a `#`.

Comment: Thanks! Will investigate yours but the match approach seems to do the trick. The '+' and '#' identify `foo` only to the extent that they may be in some combination before and after it. There is no guarantee that it is terminated by a `+` although will usually be the case. Hope that helps.

Comment: So it's as simple as the first segment of text preceded and followed by any combination of `+` and `#`?